# PFQueryTableViewController not showing images when using Storyboards

Tags: parse-platform

I have done a lot of research to figure out why this is happening and tried numerous things without success.
I am using the PFQueryTableViewController to pull data from parse.com. I am using Storyboards.  I am not using a custom table view cell, just the regular PFTableViewCell.

Data is pulled from parse, text in the cell is displayed as expected, but no images are shown. Even the placeholder image is not shown. When debugging, I can observe that the _remoteImageView property of the PFTableViewCell is nil. I think this is because the prototype cell in the Storyboard does not have an image view. But the prototype cell is tied to PFTableViewCell in Custom Class.

Things I have tried:

- initialize my custom TableViewController (derived from PFQueryTableViewController) via initWithCoder (not from initWithStyle). Did not work.
- call [cell.imageView loadInBackground] after setting cell.imageView file to the PFFile with the image in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Did not work.

If I do not use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier and directly instantiate the cell with initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier, the images are shown!! But the segue does not work (it does not go to the detail view).

Please help!
See code below:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"RestaurantType";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"text";

       // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
        self.imageKey = @"image";

       // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
       self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

       // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
       self.paginationEnabled = YES;

       // The number of objects to show per page
       self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }

    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    if (self.objects.count == 0)
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

    [query orderByAscending:@"type"];

    return query;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TypeCell";

    PFTableViewCell* cell = (PFTableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"type"];
    PFFile *thumbnail = object[@"image"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon58x58.png"];
    cell.imageView.file = thumbnail;

    return cell;
}
```